# Ajax jQuery not working after rewriting url

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have problem why this is not working. 
i modify the .htaccess to remove .php extension

so this is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
        RewriteEngine on

        # To remove trailing slash
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
        RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

        # To remove .php extension
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ (.*)\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

        # To check whether the file exists then set it back internally
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L]

        # To redirect /index to root
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
        RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

        </IfModule>
```

and this is my ajax code

```
function setStatus(response) {
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'status?status',
    data:{response:response},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response){
    $('#status').text(response.status);
    $('#fight_number').text(response.fight_no);
    $('#result').text(response.result);
    $('#total_bet').text("Total Bet Points : " + response.total_bet_points);
    $('#points').text("Your Points : " + response.user_points);
    $('#meron_counter').text(response.m_side);
    $('#wala_counter').text(response.w_side);
    $('#draw_counter').text(response.d_side);
    $('#cancel_counter').text(response.c_side);
    $('#ol').text(response.online_count);
    var au = $('.audio').attr('id')
    if(response.status_now === 500) {
    if(response.events === au) {
     setAudio(response.chat_type);
     }
    }
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

  }
});
```

}

the code is working fine before modify the htaccess and remove the .php
so i made a change in ajax i from status.php?status to status?status

why this is not working

thank you

Comment: ...and what's the error you get when "it's not working" ?

Comment: not displaying to html, but if i use button click and response to ajax its working, the only not working is not display to html page

Comment: What do you get with `success:function(response) { console.log(response); }` ?

Comment: its working im get response

Comment: Getting "a response" is not synonymous with "working".  If the response is *"you request failed"* then it's not "working".

Comment: nevermind i fallback my site , im not removing .php now